# Change checkout redirection to custom page (2.2.4)

Tags: magento2, checkout, cart, url

I've created a custom page where I submit my cart to create an order.

Now, on the checkout/cart page, when I click on the button to go to the payment, I want to go to my custom page.

I try many things (changes into JS, changes into html...) but I did achieved nothing. How can I do that (the proper way ^^) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ANSWER : change in proceed-to-checkout.js  :

> location.href = config.checkoutUrl;

to

> location.href = '/your/custom/url';

And don't forget to clear your cache (I haven't done it the first time...)